# Showing that $\lambda\perp \nu$ with $\nu(E)=\displaystyle \sum_{\left\{k:r_k\in E\right\}} \frac{w_k}{2^k}$ and $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(r_n)\subset \mathbb{Q}$ sequence of rationals  and $(w_n)\subset \mathbb{C}$ bounded. Let $\nu(E)=\displaystyle \sum_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}:r_k\in E\right\}} \frac{w_k}{2^k},\, E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. If $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ show that $\lambda\perp \nu$.

Hi. In this problem I thought about considering the sets $A=\left\{r_n\right\}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{r_n\right\}$. With this, $\lambda(\left\{r_n\right\})\leq \lambda(\mathbb{Q})=0$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ countable and
$\displaystyle \nu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{r_n\right\})=\sum_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{N}:r_k\in E\right\}} \frac{w_k}{2^k}=\sum_{\emptyset} \frac{w_k}{2^k}=0$
but I suppose that is wrong because I do not use anywhere that the sequence $(w_n)$ is bounded. Besides the fact that I get a sum over an empty set which doesn't make much sense ...

What sets $A$, $B$ do you recommend me to take?

Comment: Perhaps, they want to deal only with sigmed measure which do not take the values $\pm \infty$. Boundeness of $(w_n)$ makes $|\nu|$ a finite measure. Your proof is correct.

Comment: I need to add that $\nu$ is a measure with complex value

Comment: If $(w_n)$ is not bolunded then $\nu$ need be a complex valued measure.

Comment: I understand the arguments. I am in doubt if the sum of an empty set is zero?

Comment: Of course, it is. That is understod in the definition of $\nu$.